# Whats wrong with the FRBR RDF-Ontology? What does "Use of non-absolute IRI" mean?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology

I am trying to import a RDF-Ontology to Protégé or to [webvowl](http://www.visualdataweb.de/webvowl/). There seems to be a problem with the RDF-File, because the import doesn't work, I always get an error (parsing failed).

The ontology I want to use is [FRBR-Core](https://vocab.org/frbr/frbr-core-20050810).  In addition to FRBR-Core, there is also the ontology [FRBR-Extended](https://vocab.org/frbr/extended). Oddly,the RDF-File for FRBR-Extended can be imported to Webvowl and Protégé, so this file does work.
I looked at the RDF-Files of both core and extended version, hoping that I would find a difference that explains, why one file does work and the other doesn't, but I couldn't find anything.

I copied the FRBR-Core-Ontology into the [OWL Validator](http://visualdataweb.de/validator/validate), to see what's wrong. The error I get is:
[image: owl validation error for FRBR-Core]

Does anyone understand what that means? Or does anyone know at all, what the problem with FRBR-Core is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous answer: this is correct in its description of why relative IRIs are a problem, but wrong in thinking it applies here.

> The ontology iri in the file starts with `string:`, which is not a valid network protocol(edit: according to the validator. The protocol is valid but the validator is restricted to urn:, http:, https:). Therefore, the IRI is relative, meaning that it will be resolved against the base IRI if one is present, or the file location otherwise.
>
> Given that you're seeing this violation, it means none of these mechanisms was available.
>
> IRIs in an ontology cannot be relative, they must be absolute - otherwise the assertions will change according to where the file is parsed from. This is a violation of the OWL specs, and is what is being highlighted here.

I've tried the ontology in the validator and tried the code with OWLAPI 4 validation and directly in Protege. So, the following came up:

- the online validator you used is manually adding an ontology IRI, because the ontology itself does not have a declaration (Protege gives the following warning on loading:

  INFO  08:02:37  Loading ontology from http://purl.org/vocab/frbr/frbr-core-20050810.rdf
  INFO  08:02:41  Notice: root element does not have an xml:base. Relative IRIs will be resolved against http://purl.org/vocab/frbr/frbr-core-20050810.rdf
- loading from the URL of the page you ave does not work - HTML is downloaded instead. I'm not sure if this is a content negotiation issue or if the ontology was only meant to be accessible via the link inside the page. Using this link works:

  http://purl.org/vocab/frbr/frbr-core-20050810.rdf

There are other OWL 2 DL violations, but they shouldn't stop you from using the ontology.

```
Use of undeclared class: <http://web.resource.org/cc/Work> [ClassAssertion(<http://web.resource.org/cc/Work> <http://purl.org/vocab/frbr/frbr-core-20050810.rdf>) in OntologyID(OntologyIRI(<http://purl.org/vocab/frbr/frbr-core-20050810.rdf>) VersionIRI(<null>))]
Use of undeclared annotation property: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator>
Use of undeclared annotation property: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/issued>
Use of undeclared annotation property: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#changeNote>
Use of undeclared annotation property: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#example>
Use of undeclared annotation property: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#historyNote>
Use of undeclared annotation property: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#definition>
Use of reserved vocabulary for data property IRI: rdf:value [DataPropertyAssertion(rdf:value _:genid2147483651 "application/rdf+xml")
Use of reserved vocabulary for data property IRI: rdf:value [DataPropertyAssertion(rdf:value _:genid2147483649 "text/html")
```

Comment: Minor remark: `sting` is a scheme, therefore `string:ontology` is an absolute IRI, not relative. See official spec https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3987
Also, Apache Jena thinks it is an absolute IRI, consider the following construction `org.apache.jena.iri.IRIFactory.iriImplementation().create("string:ontology").isAbsolute()`

Comment: My bad - take this as an explanation of why the validator thinks there's a problem in the ontology.